# Query Not working with Table in SQL server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, sybase

I have a java application which copies all data from one table of sybase database to another database (sql server 2008). This works fine and I am using jTDS. Now I want to select data from the table column containing value "FLM" and "NONFLM". I executed query

```
select * from table where colName = 'FLM'
```

in sql server but returned no result. I trimmed this column but could not get result.The table has column with "FLM" value. Same thing is with other column I can't find whitespace in any of those only column where integer value was copied into string column works. I have all column as string.

Comment: What do you get when you use `colName LIKE '%FLM%'`?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal It works when using like.

Comment: Ok, next try: What do you get for `SELECT colName, LEN(colName) FROM table WHERE colName LIKE '%FLM%'`

Comment: @OcasoProtal It return 4 for FLM for SELECT colName, LEN(colName) FROM table WHERE colName LIKE 'FLM%'

Comment: One more ;): `SELECT colName, LEN(colName), ASCII(substring(colName,4,1)) FROM table WHERE colName LIKE 'FLM%'` Probably you'll get 13 for ASCII, thus a CR is added to each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments, there is one character too much in your column. So either adjust your java import (`String#trim()` ?) or update the values in your table:

```
UPDATE table SET colName = SUB(colName,0,LEN(colName))   
WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(colName,LEN(colName),1)) = 0
```

**Beware!** This is untested, so wrap it in a transaction before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where colName IN ('FLM', 'NONFLM')
```

Comment: This gives empty result from SSMS. Actually I want to select only FLM. Something has happend to data while it's being transported.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may reside on the database.

Try:

```
use databasename
go
select * from table where colName = 'FLM'
go
```

or:

```
select * from databasename..table where colName = 'FLM'
```

---

Also, if you should use `IN` to find more than one:

```
select * from databasename..table where colName IN ('FLM', 'NONFLM')
```

Answer (score -1):

This Query is correct,

May be you have not selected the correct Database...

what is the result when you run this

select * from table

Comment: The query isn't correct as the OP is looking for results where the colName is FLM or NONFLM